# Print array outside the loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array called `users` with users who is assigned to a project. 
Ex: USERID "1,2,3,4 and 5"

I'm trying to get all user id from that array och print it out in a separate variable. The code below works great inside the loop. It get all user id and printing it out like this "12345"

But when I printing it out outside the loop its only printing the last id "5".

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
   // THIS WRITE ALL USER ID
   echo $key = sprintf( '%s', $value['id'] );
}

// I WANT TO GET ALL USERID HERE (OUTSIDE THE LOOP). 
// RIGHT NOW IT ONLY WRITE THE LAST USER ID     
echo $key = sprintf( '%s', $value['id'] );
```

Sorry for my bad english ☺️

**EDIT**

Thanks to Philipp Maurer I finaly got it to work! ☺️ 
What I'm trying to do next is to send a notification to each user.
`$row` = user id.

Nothing happens if I write it like this:

```
$ids = array_column($users, 'id');
    $userid = implode(', ', $ids);

    $data=explode(',',$userid);

    foreach($data as $row) 
    {
        $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $row, 'new_action', $vars );
    }
```

But if I manually write `$userid = "1, 5, 8";` (the same as it write out from the array)  it send correct to every user.

Comment: Every iteration of that loop is overwriting the previous value of $key, so you end up with only the last value assigned to key

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all user ids from your array, you can use `array_column`, which will retrieve the specified field from each element in your array. [array_column documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$ids = array_column($users, 'id');
```

Then you can use `implode` to add all together to a single string and echo it. [implode documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
echo implode(', ', $ids);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4653efc9c5a0a2bc0d27fd48d6ca626bef3741e7)

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration replaces your `$key` variable, use `implode()` function on `$users` keys:

```
echo implode(',', array_keys($users));
```

**EDIT**: added correct syntax